# Pywinauto Taskbar - Clicking on Further options

Tags: python, user-interface, automation, taskbar, pywinauto

My Taskbar:-
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/952l2.png)

Taskbar after clicking on the arrow :-

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/diitx.png)

What is Want to do is, after right clicking on a application in taskbar, can i fut=rther click on more options ?

My code so far :-

```
from pywinauto import taskbar
taskbar.TaskBar.Button.click_input()
popup_dlg = taskbar.explorer_app.window(class_name='NotifyIconOverflowWindow')
popup_toolbar = popup_dlg.Overflow_Notification_Area
print(popup_toolbar.texts()[1:])
popup_toolbar.button('Honeygain').click_input(button='right')
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cb7fo.png)

***The red coloured icon is the application i want to open in taskbar.
The name of the red coloured icon is "User profile not ready for dictation".
In my code, i have written to right click on the red coloured icon.
But many more further options show up.***

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIbN3.png)

**After that, i want to click on tools
and  after that, i want to click on transcribe recording.**

*control_identifiers:-*

```
Toolbar - 'Overflow Notification Area'    (L1416, T835, R1556, B975)
['Overflow Notification Area', 'Overflow Notification AreaToolbar', 'Toolbar']
child_window(title="Overflow Notification Area", class_name="ToolbarWindow32")
```

Comment: Are you on windows 7? Can you also add the `dump_tree()` of the popup menu?

Comment: First thing is, I am on Windows 11. Can you elaborate what is dump tree ?

Comment: dump_tree() is something that prints the control identifiers of the application. just like html tags for the webelements. or you must be using `print_identifiers()` instead `dump_tree()`

Comment: I updated the question. See the Control_Identifiers in the question

Answer (score 0):

I have similar case. I'm trying to right-click "CCleaner" and then click the option "Options".

[CCleaner in system tray](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ui6IT.png)

I am using these codes below.

```
from pywinauto.application import Application
from pywinauto import Desktop

dsk = Desktop(backend='uia')
explorer = Application(backend="uia").connect(path="explorer.exe")
sys_tray = explorer.window(class_name="Shell_TrayWnd")

# app_window = sys_tray.child_window(title="insert the name of application").click_input(button='right')

app_window = sys_tray.child_window(title="CCleaner").click_input(button='right')

# dsk.Context.*insertthenameofoption*.click_input()

dsk.Context.Options.click_input()
```

maybe you can improve my codes.

Comment: you can do that with pywinauto by taking screenshot of your taskbar and after click direclty on that image.